# How to keep .bar() formatting when exporting to excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, export-to-excel

I have successfully exported other type of formatting (as background & font color), but I am struggling when trying to export

```
df_user_export = df_user.apply(lambda x : 
x.drop(x.index[:1])).style.format(precision =0).bar()
df_user_export # is the df i want to have
```

I have tried the below code for exporting background and font but no luck with .bar()

```
df_user_export .to_excel('df_user_export 
.xlsx',sheet_name='df_user_export', engine='openpyxl')
```

I would like to keep the format I am getting in python (screenshot attached)

Thanks in advance for your help
Note: I have researched for long time and even checked the documentation for openpyxl & pandas and could not find anything

I have tried the below code for exporting background and font but no luck with .bar()

```
df_user_export .to_excel('df_user_export 
.xlsx',sheet_name='df_user_export', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the to_excel() method does not support exporting the formatting created by the .bar() method.

One workaround is to export the data to a CSV file and then manually apply the formatting in Excel. Another option is to use a third-party library such as XlsxWriter or openpyxl to export the data and apply the formatting

Comment: ooh such a shame!! I think it is my first time facing this (aka something that is not really built in yet) 

Thanks a lot @magedo for your answer! 

I believe in this case , the best approach would be : 
1- Save excel file
2-Open & write
3-Apply Barchart function/viz logic
4-Save file again with PROPER NAME

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution. first create a dataframe and apply the bar chart formatting using .style.bar().  then save the dataframe to an Excel file using pd.ExcelWriter(). load the workbook and worksheet from the saved file using openpyxl.load_workbook(). We then add a color scale rule to the cells with the scores using